# Is it possible to change default entry point

Tags: go

`go build`/`go run` are waiting for the `main` function inside the `main` package.

Is it possible, via command line options, to specify another "entrypoint" like `mainFoo()`

Comment: No, this is fixed in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution).

Comment: The entrance must be main.main, runtime.main starts main.main.

Answer (score -1):

As @Marc said, the short answer is NO.

BUT, if you would like to create a command line application with more than one "entrypoint" you could use [cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra).
You could create as many commands as you wish. :)

Comment: I didn't wanted one binary with multiple commands, but two distinct binaries.

Comment: In this case, your question above wasn't clear enough. Please, provide more details.